# WriteableBitmapEx Windows Phone dll's

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, writeablebitmapex

I am currently trying to overlay two bitmaps using [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) using this method found in the documentation:

```
writeableBmp.Blit(new Point(10, 10), bitmap, sourceRect, 
        Colors.White,WriteableBitmapExtensions.BlendMode.Additive);
```

I installed the package via NuGet which adds ...WinPhone.dll and WinPhoneXnaDependant.dll which seems to cause the problem. Here's the code I'm currently writing:

```
WriteableBitmap result = new WriteableBitmap(results, null);
WriteableBitmap overlay = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0).FromResource("Images/VizageOverlay.png");
var cropped = result.Crop(96, 0, 480, 728);
cropped.Blit(new Point(0, 0), overlay, new Point(0,0), 
        WriteableBitmapExtensions.BlendMode.Additive);
```

However, an error states that the **WriteableBitmapExtensions.BlendMode.Additive** **exists in both** the aforementioned dlls. I've tried getting rid of both and keeping one but I need both it appears for the above code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Qualify each of them you use with it's namespace: `WriteableBitmap Result = new WinPhone.WriteableBitmap()` (or whatever the proper namespace is for them respectively).

Comment: for some reason I'm not able to do that as they both extend System.Windows.Media.Imaging

Comment: it appears to be working now though I'm none the wiser why - are building a couple of times it now works

Comment: I'm not sure why it would change, either. Glad you got it working, though. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the reference to the `WinPhoneXnaDependant` if you're not creating a XNA project.

If the problem persists, ping the author, René Schulte [on Twitter](http://twitter.com/rschu).

Answer (score 1):

Never saw that. A rebuild might help and you can just remove the reference to the XNA project. The WriteableBitmapExWinPhoneXnaDependant.dll contains XNA-dependent code like write to MediaLibrary. It's separated so the WBX lib can be used in background agents which prohibits the usage of such XNA code.